# React Component not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Foo is being displayed but not Bar. I am following a tutorial but using a different api but everything is the same, so I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import movieDB from './themoviedb-javascript-library/themoviedb';

const movieList = () => {
return (
  <p>
  Bar
  </p>
);
}

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { movies: [] };

movieDB.search.getMovie({ "query":"Fight Club" }, (movies) => {
  // console.log(this)
  this.setState({movies: movies});
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    Foo
    <movieList />
  </div>
)
}

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: try it like this: `{movieList}`

Comment: @JosanIracheta I tried that with the same thinking but that also doesn't work.

Comment: how about `{movieList()}`

Comment: @YifeiXu That worked, I'm confused why <movieList /> isn't working, since I thought that was how you passed in components. Also what if I want to pass in props?

Comment: @David if you want to pass in props, your declaration for `movieList` would look something like `const movieList = props => {....}`

Comment: @YifeiXu Is <component /> only used for passing in class based components then?

Comment: @David not necessarily. Components that look like `const x = props => {...}` are known as stateless components, and can also be used in the form of `<x />`

Comment: `movieList` component should be capitalized. Use `const MovieList = () => ...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components have to be capitalized. `MovieList` should work. React treats lowercase tags as html tags and doesn't try to process them.

Comment: This did it. Thank you!